# How to change Xcode4.3 Organizer's repository names

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3, xcode-organizer

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to change the repository names given by Xcode4.3's Organizer.

To emphasize this, not the repository itself should be renamed, but the name that Organizer gives that repository on clone/checkout (the names that you see in bold in the list).

I'm currently working with a lot of repositories, and especially with Git it seems that the names given by Organizer are kind of random.

With a Git Location of, say, "foo@bar.mycompany.com:repo", Organizer sometimes names the repository "foo", sometimes "foo@bar.mycompany.com" (even multiple times the same name!). In SVN, it seems that the name is always the repository name ("repo" in the example above).

Handling a list of like 20 repositories, all with more or less the same pseudo-random names, is tiresome and error-prone. Surely there must be a way to change the names Xcode assigns the repositories?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that it is applicable to XCode 4.3, but in XCode 4.5 this name defined by the folder where project is stored. Rename of the folder should change the Organizer repository name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, all my Xcode root folders are named basically the same (most likely "iOS" since most of them are part of bigger projects involving more than only one platform). Therefore, I'd need to customize the name of the repository in Xcode, and Xcode only. I guess that's not possible?

Comment: Guess so also. Lucky you, have a ton of iOS projects to code :)